# Search and replace multiple strings in a text file using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am looking to search and replace multiple strings in a file.
Input text is  (including the quotes and comma)

"height": "288px",

I want to replace it to

"height": 288,

How can I do the search and replace using powershell? The regex "(?:\d*.)?\d+px" would find "288px" but am not sure how to replace it to just 288.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather basic regular expression problem. Match a sequence of one or more consecutive digits followed by the string "px" between double quotes. Put the digits in a capturing group, so you can use a back-reference in the replacement:

```
'"height": "288px",' -replace '"(\d+)px"', '$1'
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get that working-   $Content = Get-Content "C:\xyz.dash"       
$Content -replace '"((?:\d*\.)?\d+)px"','$1'| Out-File "C:\output.txt"